# solr sort by logic based field selection

Tags: php, mysql, solr, lucene

```
SELECT id, first_qualified, publish_date, from_date, 
CASE WHEN first_qualified =0
THEN publish_date
ELSE from_date
END sortdate
FROM  `jobs` 
ORDER BY  `sortdate` DESC
```

I would like to express the above mysql query using solr Version: 3.6.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Function Queries as return fields and sort fields: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery .

This should return an additional field 'sortdate' and apply the sort order that corresponds to your SQL

```
fl=*,sortdate:if(exists(query({!v='first_qualified:0'})),publish_date,from_date)&sort=if(exists(query({!v='first_qualified:0'})),publish_date,from_date) desc
```

Note that function queries can slow down your queries. It's probably better to create a field 'sortdate' in your schema and fill it accordingly while indexing.